# QTableView not showing part of my data and resetHeaderData not fired with PyQt5 and Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, display, qtableview

This is a simple problem but I can't handle it!

1. The data source is DataFrame of pandas with Bool value,  the 2nd Column value of my tableview not is dispalyed. Why?
2. In the MainWindow Class, I reset the 2nd column's name from 'T/F' to 'True/False' (Actually just for test) using 'setHeaderData' function of 'MyTableModel' subclassed from 'QAbstractTableModel'. But the 2nd column name not changed. Why? Much Thanks!
   [image: Problem]

```
import sys
import typing
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QWidget, QTableView, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        myTable = QTableView()
        df_data = [['strong', True], ['Pretty', False]]
        df_index = ['0', '1']
        df_column = ['Type', 'T/F']
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data, index=df_index, columns=df_column)
        model = MyTableModel(df)
        model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, 'True/False', role=Qt.DisplayRole)
        myTable.setModel(model)
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(myTable)
        dummy_widget = QWidget()
        dummy_widget.setLayout(hlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(dummy_widget)


class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.header = self._data.columns.tolist()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()]
            return value

    def rowCount(self, index) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self._data.columns[section]


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `setHeaderData()` does nothing in abstract models (if you print its returned value, you'll get `False`), you have to implement it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that should be changed in Your code:

1. In Your MyTableModel.HeaderData method, You are using self._data as a source for Your header values and not self.header. Since You already have .header list there, You should use it.
2. As mentioned by [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante), You need to implement `setHeaderData` Yourself if You are using Abstract Model in View.

Here is a piece of code, that You can add to Your Model class:

```
def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
        return self.header[section]

def setHeaderData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, value: typing.Any, role: int = ...) -> bool:
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        self.header[section] = value
        self.headerDataChanged.emit(orientation, section, section)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

As mentioned in [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setHeaderData) for `setHeaderData` You should always emit `headerDataChanged` signal.

**EDIT:**
For Your question why Your bool data is not displayed.
You need to convert it into string.
So just change `data` method to this:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        value = str(self._data.iloc[index.row()][index.column()])
        return value
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Bool not displayed problem, I have done that with your 'str'. But the setHeaderData problem, I have tested many times. Finally, I found that whatever params you provide for function 'setHeaderData'， the column renaming process actually goes the way of function 'headerData'. But the value param is not sent to function 'headerData', which means the value param for setHeaderData is not used by Class. You have to re-provide a header list for the Model, for example: self.header = ['col1','col2','col3'], also column number should match old column number.  Would you check it pls?

Comment: I found that:   in the MyTableModel class' __init__, you define self.header = ['oldCol1', 'oldCol2'].    When you want to change column name, you should first do : self.model.header = ['newCol1', 'newCol2'], and then self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, anyStr, Qt.DisplayRole) . Then it's ok.  Thank you, you told me how to use emit.